# Calculate the autocorr. function of ARMA process

Tags: time-series, self-study, autocorrelation

I'm new to time series. I would like to calculate this.. but I really don't know how to begin... 
ARMA(1,2)

$X_{t}=\underbrace{\phi X_{t-1}}_{AR(1)}+\underbrace{\epsilon_{t}-\theta_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta_{2}\epsilon_{t-2}}_{MA(2)}$

AUTOCOV. FUNCTION: 
$\gamma_{t, t+h}=\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_{t}, X_{t+h})=E\left[\left(X_{t}-\mu_{t}\right)\left(X_{t+h}-\mu_{t+h}\right)\right]\right.$

AUTOCORR.FUNCTION OF $X$:
$\rho_{t, t+h}=\frac{\gamma_{t, t+h}}{\sqrt{\gamma_{t, t} \gamma_{t+h, t+h}}}=\frac{\gamma_{t, t+h}}{\sigma_{t} \sigma_{t+h}}$

All useful comments will be rewarded.

Comment: Start by finding $R_X(0)=E[X_t^2]$, and share your results with us.

Comment: Here, if $\epsilon_t$ is zero-mean, $X_t$ is zero-mean. Is $\epsilon_t$ zero-mean?

Comment: Yes it is zero-mean

Comment: Try to express the autocovariance at lag $k$, $\gamma_k=E(X_{t-k}X_t)$ in terms of $\gamma_{k-1}$.  You'll end up with a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation that you can then solve.

Comment: Something like this? $\gamma_{0}=\phi \gamma_{1}+\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2}-\theta_{1} E\left[\epsilon_{t-1} X_{t}\right]-\theta_{1} E\left[\epsilon_{t-2} X_{t}\right]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the autocovariance function satisfies
\begin{align}
\gamma_k
  &=E(X_{t-k} X_t)
\\&=E(X_{t-k} (\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t-\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta_2\epsilon_{t-2}))
\\&=\phi\gamma_{k-1} + E(X_{t-k}\epsilon_t)-\theta_1 E(X_{t-k}\epsilon_{t-1})-\theta_2 E(X_{t-k}\epsilon_{t-2}). \tag{1}
\end{align}
Setting $k=0$, (1) simplifies to 
$$
\gamma_0 = \phi\gamma_1 + \sigma_\epsilon^2(1-\theta_1(\phi-\theta_1)-\theta_2(\phi(\phi-\theta_1)-\theta_2)), \tag{2}
$$
since 
\begin{align}
E(X_{t}\epsilon_t)
  &=E((\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t-\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta_2\epsilon_{t-2})\epsilon_{t}) 
\\&=E\epsilon_t^2=\sigma_\epsilon^2, \tag{2a}
\\E(X_{t}\epsilon_{t-1})
  &=E((\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t-\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}- 
  \theta_2\epsilon_{t-2})\epsilon_{t-1}) 
\\&=\phi E(X_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-1}) -\theta_1 E\epsilon_{t-1}^2, 
\\&=\phi\sigma_\epsilon^2 - \theta_1\sigma_\epsilon^2, \tag{2b}
\\E(X_{t}\epsilon_{t-2})
  &=E((\phi X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t-\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta_2\epsilon_{t-2})\epsilon_{t-2})
\\&=\phi E(X_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-2})-\theta_2E\epsilon_{t-2}^2, 
\\&=\phi(\phi\sigma_\epsilon^2 - \theta_1\sigma_\epsilon^2)-\theta_2\sigma_\epsilon^2. \tag{2c}
\end{align}
Note how (2c) follows from (2b) which follows from (2a).

Similarly, by setting $k=1$ and $k=2$, you obtain two more equations in addition to (2) (not included since this is self-study) that you can solve for the three unknowns $\gamma_0$, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.

For $k>2$ (the order of the MA part), since $X_{t-k}$ is then uncorrelated with $\epsilon_t$, $\epsilon_{t-1}$, and $\epsilon_{t-2}$, (1) simplifies to
$$
\gamma_k=\phi \gamma_{k-1}.
$$
More generally, for an ARMA$(p,q)$ model, one can show that $\gamma_k$ for lags $k>q$ satisfies the [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation) $\phi(B)\gamma_k=0$, where $\phi(B)$ is the AR operator polynomial of the model, see e.g. [Wei (2007), ch. 3](https://www.google.com/search?q=wei%20time%20series%20analysis%20pdf&oq=wei%20time%20series%20analysis%20pdf&aqs=chrome..69i57.7803j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Therefore, having $\gamma_{t,t+h}=\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_{t},X_{t+h}=E\left[\left(X_{t}-\mu_{t}\right)\left(X_{t+h}-\mu_{t+h}\right)\right]\right.$ I deduce from $X_t$ that $\mu=0$ and therefore $\gamma_{k}=E\left(X_{t-k}X_{t}\right)$. Is this correct? Thank you for your elegant solution!

Comment: Yes, you see that the stationary mean is zero by taking expectation of the model equation an equating $E X_t$ with $E X_{t-1}$.

Comment: It is not the full solution though since it remains (for you) to find and solve equations for $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$!

Comment: I'm aware of that, I got something but it  I prefer to wait until I finish. Some advance: $\gamma_{1}=\phi_{1} \gamma_{0}+\left[\theta_{2}\left(\theta_{1}-\phi_{1}\right)-\theta_{1}\right] \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$ and $\gamma_{2}=\phi_{1} \gamma_{1}-\theta_{2} \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$ I think that I will provide a better explanation.

Comment: Do you knôw if there is a way to calculate this automatically by R?

Comment: Yes, `stats::ARMAacf` computes this (but for some reason ony the autocorrelation function), `ltsa::tacvfARMA` computes the autocovariance function.

Comment: Do you know if this is correct? $\rho_{t,t+h}=\frac{\gamma_{t,t+h}}{\sqrt{\gamma_{t,t}\gamma_{t+h,t+h}}}=\frac{\gamma_{t,t+h}}{\sigma_{t}\sigma_{t+h}}=\frac{\gamma_{t,t+h}}{\gamma_{0}}$ I'm hesitating how to calculate autocorrelations...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91864/discussion-between-jarle-tufto-and-fonaritm).

Comment: Hi, just solved: from the above formula I deduce that $\rho_{k}=\frac{\gamma_{t,t-k}}{\gamma_{t,t}}=\frac{\gamma_{k}}{\gamma_{0}}$ because $\gamma_{k}=\gamma_{t,t-k}$ I think I'm done, but I'm triying to calculate it by terms AR first RA second and join it.